# setting the scope value after the http call in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a controller in which I make an ajax call. In the success callback I assign some value to $scope variable like below.

```
$http.get(GlobalService.getDomainUrl() +'/hosts/attr').success(function(data){
       //Now that we have made the ajax call we need to first get all the config values..
        $scope.classifications = _.allKeys(data);
        var config;
        _.each(data, function(e) {
            $scope.config = _.allKeys(e);
            console.log($scope.config);
            _.each(config, function(attr){
                $scope.attributes = attr;
            });
        });
    });
```

The data from the server is in the below format:

```
  {
    "my_config": {
    "cpu": [
      "2"
    ],
    "mem": [
      "4GB"
    ]
  },
  "network_config": {
    "my_config": [
      "ON",
      "OFF",
      "NONE"
    ],
    "os_config": [
      "LINUX",
      "MS",
      "OSX"
    ]
  }
}
```

Inside my html code:

```
<div class="row">
  {{config}}
</div>
```

When I try to use the values in my html file using `{{config}}` I am seeing an empty array. On the browser console I am able to see the data since I am printing using console.log statement. Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: Try instantiating the `$scope.config` variable at the top of your controller

Comment: Tried but still not working. console messages are getting printed.

Comment: can you show your HTML?

Comment: maybe a bit more :) show the controller declaration in the HTML

Comment: @Simone Zandara Added the html section .There are other attributes that I am setting inside the controller and is reflecting on the UI except for the ones which are set inside the success function of the http.get request call.

Comment: I need to see more code to understand what is wrong. Anyway I am a bit confused by your use of var config and $scope.config

Comment: You realize that the value of $scope.config is changing on each iteration of the data object? So, if the last object is empty then $scope.config will be empty as well. But can you explain your intent? What would you expect $scope.config to ultimately look like (given your example data)?

Comment: Actually I got the issue. the config items prints correctly. The last array is empty which is overwriting the $scope.config because of which it is not displaying in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

The issue got resolved. The `$scope.config` was getting set correctly but since the last item in the array returned from the server was empty that was overwriting the value of the `scope.config`.